# How I detect what language the current system

Tags: c#

How I detect what language the current system?

[image: Taskbar]

Answer (score 6):

The "EN" label in the screenshot doesn't actually refer to the language of the system, but to a selected input keyboard. To get this information programmatically, you can use the [`CurrentInputLanguage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx) of the `InputLanguage` type.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can do the following:

```
string inputLanguage = System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
```

In case of EN you will get US as an inputLanguage value.